# ANR HeapTaskDaemon Blocked for waiting to lock an unknown object

Tags: android

Android ANR with the trace stack

And what does "waiting to lock an unknown object" mean?

```
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Blocked
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c071c0 self=0x557f72c1b0
  | sysTid=6892 nice=0 cgrp=top_visible sched=0/0 handle=0x7fa0ffe450
  | state=S schedstat=( 53102724244 2289704943 17272 ) utm=4756 stm=554 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fa0efc000-0x7fa0efe000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/6892/stack)
  native: #00 pc 0000000000019aa4  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
  native: #01 pc 000000000013adb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadEli+164)
  native: #02 pc 000000000026ad28  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+228)
  native: #03 pc 000000000026b32c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+120)
  native: #04 pc 000000000000054c  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+128)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
  - waiting to lock an unknown object
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:355)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: You've provided no context for your error. How did you get the error? What were you running? What device/OS version did this occur? Is your device running custom ROM or rooted? And of course show what you've researched.

Comment: To be fair, I can sympathize with the OPs confusion. Our tests have just randomly started failing with no known code changes, (everything is mocked so not deployments) and the only clue I have is something similar. I've spent 4 days trying to figure out if there is any other helpful info.